# Populating iOS table from Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array `_locations` which is populated from a server through a json query. I now want this array to populate a table that I have created, however it does not and it quits on `[self.delegate itemsDownLoaded:_locations];`.

If I look in the log I can see that `_locations` does get populated however, but it does not parse on that data.

Here is the full code for HomeModel2:

```
#import "HomeModel2.h"
#import "Location2.h"        

@interface HomeModel2(){
        NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation HomeModel2

- (void) downLoadItems{
    // Download the json file
    NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/service_2.php"];

    // Create the request
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

    // Create the NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

}
#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // Initialize the data object
    _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the newly downloaded data
    [_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Create an array to store the locations
    NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Parse the JSON that came in
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    // Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

        // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
        Location2 *newLocation = [[Location2 alloc] init];
        newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"Name"];
        newLocation.address = jsonElement[@"Address"];
        newLocation.latitude = jsonElement[@"Latitude"];
        newLocation.longitude = jsonElement[@"Longitude"];

        // Add this question to the locations array
        [_locations addObject:newLocation];
    }

    // Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
    if (self.delegate)
    {
        [self.delegate itemsDownLoaded:_locations];
    }
}

@end
```

.. and this is the ViewController to publish the data:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Location2.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    HomeModel2 *_homeModel;
    NSArray *_feedItems;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate and data source for the table view
    self.listTableView.delegate = self;
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self;

    // Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
    _feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // Create new HomeModel2 object and assign it to _homeModel variable
    _homeModel = [[HomeModel2 alloc] init];

    // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
    _homeModel.delegate = self;

    // Call the download items method of the home model object
    [_homeModel downLoadItems];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)itemsDownLoaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    _feedItems = items;

    // Reload the table view
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of feed items (initially 0)
    return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Get the location to be shown
    Location2 *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel.text = item.address;

    return myCell;
}

@end
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without the full code of HomeModel2, but I do see that your ViewController doesn't conform to the HomeModel2 delegate.  We can't see the type of that delegate based on what you've shared.  In addition, if `-itemsDownLoaded` is required then you don't need to check for self.delegate, as its also checked when you call the method and if its not required you should check  `[self.delegate respondestoSelector(@selector(itemsDownLoaded:))]` instead

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated the code above with the full HomeModel2. I should have the delegate defined, however I must have messed it up somehow I just can see it. Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I thick it all has to do with the delegate.self method. I read that using this in several places in your code is not the best thing and that the references easily can get messed up if you update and compile frequently. So i flushed all my old compiled data, and ran the app again from scratch and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that there is "location" objects after this piece of code:

```
// Set the downloaded items to the array
_feedItems = items;
```

or is the delegate method not even called?
i don't understand your wording...

Comment: it is as in the code displayed above. im not sure what location object you mean, i am referncing the Location2.h file further down in order to feed the items.

   ` Location2 *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];`

That file looks like this:

`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Location2 : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *latitude;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *longitude;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;


@end`

Comment: That class seems fine.
Did you try breakpoints, to check which methods are actually called.
Cause like @dmorrow is stating, you probably just messed up something regarding the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below code

```
if (self.delegate)
{
    [self.delegate itemsDownLoaded:_locations];
}
```

Use

```
// Set the downloaded items to the array
_feedItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:items];

// Reload the table view
[self.listTableView reloadData];
```

Or Change this line of code and check

Instead of

```
_feedItems = items;
```

Use

```
_feedItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:items];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: I tried implementing it but first it told me that delegate was not defined. so i updated the code to below, however now it tells me "self" is ambiguous. what is that and how do i fix it?

`-(void)itemsDownLoaded:(NSArray *)items delegate:self{
    if (self.delegate){
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    _feedItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:items];
    
    // Reload the table view
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
    }
    
}`

Comment: Check my updated answer. Remove if(self.delegate) statement and do reload directly as done above..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you ever define the delegate property, or a protocol for the delegate.

As such, you have no way of ensuring the view controller responds to the methods defined in the delegates protocol.

Can you see if the delegate method in the view controller ever gets called?